# c# ImageConverter 's ConvertFrom method return different result in .NET Framework and .NET Core

Tags: c#, .net-core, migration

I met a sticky problem when migrate .NET framework project to .NET core project.

I have a framework project used ImageConverter to convert a byte array to Bitmap. In framework, it works fine.

But when I copy same code and test in .net core, it will throw ArgumentException say 'Parameter is not valid.'

```
private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (var cn = new OdbcConnection("Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};Dbq=./Sample.mdb"))
        {
            cn.Open();
            OdbcDataAdapter adapter = new OdbcDataAdapter("select * from StudentInformation", cn);
            DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
            adapter.Fill(dataSet);

            var imageByteArr = dataSet.Tables[0].Rows[0].ItemArray[1];
            var imageConverter = new ImageConverter();
            var bitmap = imageConverter.ConvertFrom(null, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, imageByteArr);
            this.BackgroundImage = bitmap as Image;
        }
    }
```

I can see the parameter is same byte array but result is different. May be a .NET Core design or bug? Could you please help me have a look? Thanks a lot!

*I Installed this tools:

1 VS 2019 (For using .net core project)

2 .NET Core 3.0 (For .NET Core project) 
[.NET Core 3.0 download link](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/3.0)

3 ODBC engine [ODBC Engine download link](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255)

Repreduce:

open attachment

open TestInFramework project and run Click button, you can see background image changed.

open TestInCore project and run Click button, you can see a exception throw from ImageConverter's ConvertFrom method.

Please note two project use same data access file.

[.net core result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ovFwv.png)

[.net framework result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FN3Dd.png)